# What control should I use to show different content?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls

I need to show content in my Windows Phone application. It's text, images, audios, video, etc. Each `Item` has author name and image, and `List<>` content (different count). And I need to show it. There is one solution I now - use `TemplateSelector` with `Lisbox` or `LLS`. But combinations of content are >30, and  30 temlates - it's about 2000 code lines, and I think its a bad solution. I tried to make universal control, which include all the containers(controls) for content, and I populated it only those content which is in `Item` (empty containers just minimized), but perfomance is really bad(each `DataTemplate` has 10-11 controls). Solution with one control is good, but I need a good perfomance. Is there any way to solve this promlem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to display different pushpin in Windows Phone. 
I did an usercontrol and set a specific Template in code-behind :

```
public partial class Map : UserControl
{
    public Map()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += Map_Loaded;
    }

    void Map_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).LoadingItemsCompleted += OnLoadingItemsCompleted;
    }

    private void OnLoadingItemsCompleted(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Don't care about thats
        ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit.MapExtensions.GetChildren(map);
        MapItemsControl itemsControl = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(MapItemsControl)) as MapItemsControl;

        // Here !
        foreach (GeolocalizableModel item in (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).Items)
        {
            Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
            switch (item.PushpinTemplate)
            {
                case Server.PushpinTemplate.First:
                    pushpin.Template = this.Resources["firstPushpinTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
                    break;
                case Server.PushpinTemplate.Second:
                    pushpin.Template = this.Resources["secondPushpinTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
                    break;
                case Server.PushpinTemplate.Third:
                    pushpin.Template = this.Resources["thirdPushpinTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (PushpinTemplate != null) pushpin.Template = PushpinTemplate;
                    break;
            }

            pushpin.Content = item.PushpinContent;
            pushpin.GeoCoordinate = item.Location;
            itemsControl.Items.Add(pushpin);
        }
    }

    public ControlTemplate PushpinTemplate
    {
        get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(PushpinTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PushpinTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PushpinTemplate.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PushpinTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PushpinTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(Map), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Templates are defined in the UserControl.